# Issue with Ryan Fait's custom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently having issue with Ryan Fait's custom elements script (jQuery addon for customizing form elements like radio/checkbox/select).
Problem that I'm having is with checkboxes. Thing is - user needs to click two times on checkbox to actually select it, or just click one time on label.
HTML code link: http://www.pastie.org/2344594
On the other hand, if there's no  tag for styled checkbox, it's all working fine.
What can be the cause of this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is that it's got something to do with the fact that you've got `<label>` elements wrapped around the checkboxes. That may be causing events that are fooling the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question answered:

> For this script to work properly with labels, label must not be
>   wrapped around input, it should be wrapped around actual label and it
>   should contain FOR attribute. Thanks Pointy for your comment even tho
>   I resolved this question bit before you posted it :)